# htaccess syntax issue when moving script to a subfolder

Tags: apache-2.4, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, scripting, cpanel

I have recently purchased a script but this script only works in public_html folder . I need to install it in a subfolder named shop ( public_html/shop/ ) . Now the following .htaccess rules work perfectly when the script is placed in public_html but as soon as I move it to the shop folder , everything stops working . How should I edit the following htaccess rules to make it work in /shop folder ?

```
Options All -Indexes

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(template/)
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> RewriteBase /
> RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(template/)
> RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
> ```

For this to work in the subdirectory, you need to:

- Remove the `RewriteBase` directive entirely. (It's not being used anyway currently.)
- Remove the slash prefix on the *substitution* string in the last rule.

Additionally:

- The parenthesis in the last *condition* (`RewriteCond` directive) are superfluous. And this *condition* should be first, not last (for optimisation).
- The `<IfModule>` wrapper is superfluous and should be removed. (Assuming you also have a closing `</IfModule>` "tag"?)
- `Options +FollowSymLinks` is also superfluous given the preceding `Options All` directive.
- The `RewriteRule` *pattern* in the HTTP to HTTPS redirect (ie. `(.*)`) does not need to be capturing.

Bringing the above points together, we have:

```
Options All -Indexes

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !template/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

This will now work regardless of the directory the script is installed in (root or subdirectory).